# Generate sequence of numbers prefix with an alphabet

Tags: vb.net, numbers, sequence, generated

I would like to generate a sequence of numbers as "A0000"(ie.. an alphabet followed by 4numbers not randomly generated numbers).

I have gone through this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491733/Auto-generated-sequence-number-in-SQL-Server) which is done with Sql Server similarly how can I achieve it in VB.Net.

Here is the code for SQL Server:

```
create function CustomerNumber (@id int) 
returns char(5) 
as 
begin 
return 'C' + right('0000' + convert(varchar(10), @id), 4) 
end
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How do you plan to create it in VB.Net and prevent duplicate ID's?

Comment: I want the user ID to be generated automatically on the form load event not accepting any duplicates by checking it with the previously entered values in database.

Comment: Is the application used by only a single user at a time?  What if user A loads the form, gets an ID, then user B loads the page as well before user A finishes submitting the form and gets the same ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the same:

```
"C" & id.ToString("d4")
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/vO4j9C)

Comment: this will be "C456456" if input id is 456456, I'm not sure what OP was asking for , but this isn't 4 digits

Comment: Thanks tim for your time..:)

Comment: I aswered a lot of time before and my answer is the same! T_T

Comment: @SysDragon: Yes, but your answer results in a compiler error. http://ideone.com/hLKiCY You've probably meant `.ToString("0000")`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh come on. Quotes left. Its hard enought for us to gain reputation points against pros like you. I answered sooner and is the same code. Not fair =/

Comment: @SysDragon: 1. this was the first working solution  2. i'm not the one who accepts 3. `ToString(0000)` is not the same as `ToString("d4")` 4. upvoted your answer because it works too (it's not _fair_ to downvote competitive answers  btw)

Answer (score 4):

The same function in VB.NET:

```
Function CustomerNumber(id As Integer) As String
    return "C" & id.ToString("0000")
End Function
```